# HTML code to open PuTTY client from browser

Tags: html, putty

I am trying to make a webpage which will have the entire inventory of servers that our team manages in the form of a table. I am using a simple LAMP stack and the inventory input as a CSV file.

The table has three columns: Hostname, IP address and device serial number.

While this works perfectly fine, I want to take this a step further and make every IP address in the table a hyperlink, clicking which will open an SSH client, which will connect to that IP address. Any cues to how this can be done? I was hoping there would be something like the the `mailto:` tag which opens an email client (Outlook window).

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/205836/146085

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've done it following [the info of this blog post](http://johnsofteng.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/launch-putty-from-browser/).

For future reference in case the original page becomes missing, here is the process:

1. you cannot directly map the ssh:// scheme to PuTTY, but you can map it to an intermediary script which will in turn launch PuTTY with the right arguments. Mine is called putty_ssh.bat and has the following content:

   ```
   @echo off
   set var=%1
   set extract=%var:~6,-1%
   start "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" %extract%
   ```
2. the script has to be registered in the registry. You can just create a ssh.reg file with the following content and open it (customizing last line as needed):

   ```
   REGEDIT4
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh]
   @="URL:ssh Protocol"
   "URL Protocol"=""
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell]
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open]
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open\command]
   @="\"C:\\path\\to\\putty_ssh.bat\" %1"
   ```

When I click on `ssh://` links in web pages, it now opens PuTTY.

Answer (score 4):

PuTTY unfortunately [does not associate itself](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/ssh-url-scheme.html) with the `ssh://` or any other URLs.

You can associate an application with a protocol manually. But it's not trivial. For instructions, see below.

Easier way is to install [WinSCP SFTP client](https://winscp.net/). WinSCP 5.9 and newer [registers itself to handle the `ssh://` URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url#handling) and [opens the session specified by the URL in PuTTY](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#url).

So basically, if you just install WinSCP, it will make PuTTY handle the `ssh://` URLs, without the below manual tweaks.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

To register an application manually, see the MSDN article [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)).

Basically you add a registry key like:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh]
@="URL: SSH Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\PuTTY.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\PuTTY.exe\""
```

Though the above passes a whole URL to the PuTTY command-line. And PuTTY does not understand the `ssh://` prefix. So you would have to add a wrapper script that strips the `ssh://` and passes only a user and a host to PuTTY.

For that see:
https://johnsofteng.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/launch-putty-from-browser/

---