# launching PUTTY from web browser without having .reg file

Tags: html, browser, putty, openssh

I was looking to launch putty from web browser.Most of the solutions i got was to create a ssh.reg file which contains ssh:// mapping and has to be registered in the registry ([HTML code to open putty client from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670067/html-code-to-open-putty-client-from-browser/29668048#29668048).Since) i do not have the admin rights I am not able to merge the .reg file.So i am looking for an alternative solution that does not require a merging of .reg file. Is it possible to achieve through batch file directly? .Or some other way around.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Re-posted and answered on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/902742/launching-putty-from-web-browser-without-having-reg-file Please delete this copy.