# Is it possible to modify custom protocol argument on execution?

Tags: windows, powershell, ftp, registry, filezilla

I need to open an ftp url exactly with FileZilla. To prevent a browser from opening the link by itself there is the custom protocol *fz-ftp://* defined via Windows Registry.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\fz-ftp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\FileZilla\\FileZillaPortable.exe\" \"%1\""
```

However, as FileZilla does not understand fz-ftp://, I need a way to erase the "fz-" substring from the parameter "%1" passed to FileZilla in the Registy entry.
No third party tools are allowed, only FileZilla, clean browser and Windows standard software.

**The questions are:**

1. Is it at least possible to modify parameters inside custom protocols Registry definitions?
2. Is there a workaround with PowerShell?
3. An alternative to open ftp links in FileZilla from a web-page is greeted.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: you need to write a script that does this and then calls FileZilla with the modified argument, and change the "open" command to that script. This is fairly trivial, even in batch.

Comment: For an example of such script (batch), see [HTML code to open PuTTY client from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17670067/850848).

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can set the FTP protocol handler to Filezilla at `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations`. Then you should be able to have a Desktop Shortcut (`.lnk`) point to an `ftp://` url and open it in the default program you selected for the FTP protocol.

If you want to click on an FTP link in the *browser* and have it open in an external program, web browsers typically won't let you overwrite its internal protocol handler without use of a plugin or extension. In other words you can't set it as a regular browser setting. In this case it would be best just to give the FTP URL and instruct your users to connect to the site with Filezilla or their preferred FTP client.

Either way, your best bet is not to use a custom URL protocol like you are with `fz-ftp://`.