# Open PuTTY from a webpage to run a specific command

Tags: html, forms, putty

How can I open a PuTTY session and run a specific command on the click on a HTML button?

I tried stuffs like creating a script and running it manually but could not figure out a way to implement it on the click of a button from the webpage. The command will be received from the user in the form of a text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A webpage cannot do random stuff with software installed on local machine. That would be a security nightmare.

If you can register a protocol handler on the local machine, that can do, what you need, using information stored in a URL, then it's doable. For a first step, see [HTML code to open PuTTY client from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17670067/850848).

Though you will have to improve the handler to extract the command from the URL and pass it to PuTTY. E.g. by storing it to a local file and passing it to the PuTTY using `-m` switch.

The URL could be like `runinputty://username@hostname/command` – with all components (particularly the `command`) having been properly URL-encoded.