# Open the Client's Desktop Application using a button Click from Browser - Python/HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, putty

I want to open the desktop application(For eg: Notepad/Powerpoint/Putty). Attaching an image of how it works on sharepoint.

Example image of how Microsoft Teams gets opened on the Click of the button is attached. I need this exact replica.
[On Clicking Open Microsoft Teams. Teams opens the meeting. Similarly I want to open an already installed desktop app on client's System.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOaox.png)

Similarly, I also want to open the Desktop Application of my company which is already installed.

I used Os.Popen module of Python which works locally but, when hosted does not work.
Note: OS and webbrowser module were tried.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open a random application from a browser.

You need to come up with application-specific URL and have the application register as handler for that URL. The URL has to include all details that you need in your application, like:

- `mycustomprotocol://username:password@host`
- `mycustomprotocol://call/username`

---

For an example how to implement the handlers, see:

- [HTML code to open PuTTY client from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17670067/850848#39463751) or
- [Open PuTTY from a webpage to run a specific command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71184148/850848).