# Opening Local Desktop Applications from website button

Tags: python, django, server, cron, putty

I want to open a Desktop Application from the Website button.

The Desktop Application actually uses the username and password to load so it will also be passed.

The problem is that the Website works locally but does not work when hosted...

I used OsPopen and Os.system to open the applications(which works locally).

```
os.system('putty username@servername -pw password')
os.Popen('putty username@servername -pw password')
```

Custom Protocol Handler was tried but I am not able to pass the username and Password.

Any Help would be really appreciated and would do wonders!!

Comment: You can not open local application from a web browser directly. That would be a huge security issue. There are some ways around like registering a custom URL schema for the browser with whatever your OS offers for this.

Comment: @Klaus D. The reason that I asked this is because I've seen applications like Microsoft Team,Zoom, Visual Studio Code opening the locally available Desktop application from the browser.

Comment: (Suspiciously) similar to recent [Open the Client's Desktop Application using a button Click from Browser - Python/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71872986/850848).

Answer (score 1):

The issue come from a misunderstanding of what you're doing. In fact it does not even work locally, what is happening is that the `os.system` and `os.Popen` will perform a task on the operating system where the code is running, so in your case the server.
When you develop locally the server and your machine are the same so you see the application opening on the server and think it's on your machine since it's the same device.
When you develop on some other machine the server and the local machine are no longer the same and when the application open on the server you don't see it on your machine since they're not the same anymore.

What you're trying to do can't be done by using the `os` library, instead I'll recommend to start by reading this documentation :
https://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/How-to-run-a-desktop-application-from-a-web-page